# Ubuntu 9.10 broadcom 4312 off at boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, wireless-networking, broadcom

The card uses a momentary switch to turn on at and off and it doesn't work. I read that there is a way to have the card turn on by default on boot but I can't figure out how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to boot into windows, do this, turn on the wifi, then reboot into Linux.